# Monotonic stacks and queues. Definition and examples

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, stack

What exactly is a monotonic stack? (and e.g. how is it different from a monotonic queue?)

E.g. consider the following array of integers: `[0, 2, 1, 3, 4]`. If I process this array left to right inserting it into a monotonically decreasing stack, what am I supposed to see in the stack, and why?

---

[Here](http://www.leetcode-solution.com/2019/06/01/1017-odd-even-jump.html)'s an example for a monotonically decreasing stack in Python that apparently is used in many solutions that solve [the odd-even jump problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/odd-even-jump/):

```
def make(A):
    result = [None] * N
    stack = []  # invariant: stack is decreasing
    for i in A:
        while stack and i > stack[-1]:
            result[stack.pop()] = i
        stack.append(i)
    return result
```

If I run it on the following input `A = [0, 2, 1, 3, 4]` I get `[2, 3, 3, 4, None]`. I find it odd because it includes two 3's, and a `None` value. Is this actually correctly implementing a monotonic stack?

Comment: Monotonic stack is a stack either in increasing order or decreasing order. Suppose the stack is in decreasing order than the elements in the stack should be in decreasing order. So when you want to push an element if it is greater than the top element of the stack than you cannot push in the stack so you keep poping from it till you reach a value that is less than the element you want to push.

Comment: The result array is basically telling the next greater element for the element at index i. Btw there is no implementation of monotonic stack of something it's just if you want to insert in increasing order or decreasing you need to pop to always make the stack stay in order.

Comment: Thx @WasimAhmad - when you say _"the result array is basically telling the next greater element for the element at index i."_ That's helpful. Is it fair to say that this result array is **not** a monotonic stack per se (it just provides a way of traversing the original array monotonically)? Separately, when you say _"there is no implementation of a monotonic stack"_ What do you mean exactly? Are you perhaps saying that, an implementation, as in this case, could just be "a way" to read the data monotonically with a stack-like interface? Just want to make sure I understand your point correctly.

Comment: the result is not a stack. By implementation I meant you don't need to do anything special to implement a monotonic stack. You just need to insert data which is monotonic eg 1 2 3 6 10 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your example `result` is **not** a monotonic stack. I think you got confused because the *description* of the solution to the problem alludes to the use of a "monotonic stack", and the function name `make` may give you the impression that it's building it. But that's not the case.

A **monotonic decreasing stack** is a stack that will produce, when popping its elements a sequence that:

1. is **monotonically decreasing**
2. respects the LIFO (Last In First Out) ordering of the input
3. includes the last item stacked (i.e. it can purge items greater than it).

In this case, the function `make` *uses* the construction of a monotonic stack (the variable `stack`) to identify the "next greater index" (stored in `result`) for each (index) value in the array A. This is because the process of building the monotonic stack happens to identify the "next greater index" of the input as you are purging items that should not be included in the output (as per the properties above) as you stack new items.

Comment: One of your questions is, "how is it different from a monotonic queue?"  Could you please elaborate on that as well (I do not see it currently in the answer)?

Comment: good writing for monotonic queue concept: [link][1]


  [1]: https://activities.tjhsst.edu/sct/lectures/1920/2020_2_21_Monotonic_Queues.pdf