# Reaching the end of an array with a sequence of odd/even jumps

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand a Python solution to a programming puzzle that seems to use dynamic programming. I am able to follow most of the solution, but I'm struggling a bit to really formalize the solution.

The problem is stated as follows:

> You are given an integer array `A`.  From some starting index, you can
>   make a series of jumps.  The (1st, 3rd, 5th, ...) jumps in the series
>   are called "odd" numbered jumps, and the (2nd, 4th, 6th, ...) jumps in
>   the series are called even numbered jumps.
>
> You may jump **forward** from index `i` to index j (with `i < j`) in the following way:
>
> - During **odd** numbered jumps (ie. jumps 1, 3, 5, ...), you jump to the index `j` such
>     that `A[i] <= A[j]` and `A[j]` is the **smallest** possible value.  If there
>     are multiple such indexes `j`, you can only jump to the smallest such
>     index j.
> - During **even** numbered jumps (ie. jumps 2, 4, 6, ...), you jump
>     to the index `j` such that `A[i] >= A[j]` and `A[j]` is the **largest** possible
>     value.  If there are multiple such indexes `j`, you can only jump to the
>     **smallest** such index `j`.
> - It may be the case that for some index `i` are **no legal** jumps.
>
> A starting index is **good** if, starting from that index, you can reach the end of the array by jumping some number of times (possibly 0 or more than once.)
>
> We ask that you return the number of **good starting** indices.

Below I show a solution in Python to this problem that a few authors have published.  I understand how it builds `oddnext` and `evennext` and what these arrays technically hold (the index location one jumps to from that index with an odd or even jump). What I don't understand is how the last loop works, and what's the precise dynamic programming formulation behind it.

```
def odd_even_jumps(self, A):
    N = len(A)

    def make(B):
        ans = [None] * N
        stack = []  # invariant: stack is decreasing
        for i in B:
            while stack and i > stack[-1]:
                ans[stack.pop()] = i
            stack.append(i)
        return ans

    B = sorted(range(N), key = lambda i: A[i])
    oddnext = make(B)
    B.sort(key = lambda i: -A[i])
    evennext = make(B)

    odd = [False] * N
    even = [False] * N
    odd[N-1] = even[N-1] = True

    # Why does this loop start from the end? 

    for i in range(N-2, -1, -1):
        if oddnext[i] is not None:
            odd[i] = even[oddnext[i]]
        if evennext[i] is not None:
            even[i] = odd[evennext[i]]

    return sum(odd)
```

Comment: What did you learn when you traced the program?  What did you get when you printed `odd` and `even` with various test arrays?  I don't see those efforts presented in this question.

Comment: Thanks @Prune I just updated the OP to clarify that, and posted my own answer to the question. I tried to make it as useful as possible for others who may want to understand how this problem accepts a dynamic programming solution, and how to formalize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part of the algorithm [identifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199170/monotonic-stacks-and-queues-definition-and-examples) for any given index of the input array, where do you jump to to with an odd (`oddNext`) or even (`evenNext`) jump. Some indices are populated with `None` because you can't make any  legal (even or odd) jumps from them.

Once you have this information, to answer your question, please note the following:

- Any index that can legally jump to a good index **must** be a good index (you can "re-use" the solution for that good index to reach the end)
- The **last index** of the input array is always a "good index" (i.e. you reached the end already)

As a result, you can proceed *backwards* from the end of the array to identify **good indices** by checking if they would jump **forward** to an index that you already identified as a good (or not good) index.

Note that this is a **dynamic programming** calculation, since you are establishing a recurrent relationship between good indices and exploiting it as you go backwards in the array (i.e. you are solving the dynamic programming subproblems in what's called a "bottom up" fashion, as per their dependency structure).

One thing to note is that this algorithm computes if an index is good or not for *every* location and *every* possible type of jump (i.e. we fully populate the `odd` and `even` arrays). That's because, as you iterate in the dynamic programming calculations, different starting points of the array may *need* to make an odd or even jump from that index, *even if*, when *starting* from any particular index, you can only do so with an *odd* jump as per the problem statement.

That's fine. In dynamic programming one often solves **all subproblems** even if the solution to the **original problem** doesn't rely on all of them. Note that this is also **why** in the end you only care about which indices in the `odd` array are good indices. The `even` array was just part of the dynamic programming scaffolding to populate the `odd` array.

Answer (score 1):

every iteration you check if this index has an odd jump
if it does 
it check the jump destination
if you where in the destination and had an even jump
could you reach the end
if so
this index value in odd should be true

then you check the same for even
(do i have an even jump? its dest is index with true in odd?, set the even value true)

then you return the number of odd true values because your first jump is odd

Comment: Thanks @trigonom - I provided my own answer to this question which is hopefully educational.